# Discordjs v13 addChoices() expects an array but received object

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I want to give a list of users from the database as a choice when using a command. When I use `object` where every name has a value with their discord id I get an error that it received an `object` but expected an `array`. When I try to use an `array` with just a list of names I get an error that it received a `string` but expected an `array`.

I am sure it's something obvious but I can't figure it out. I could just use `addChoice()` but I don't even want to try and I probably can't use a loop for listing all the choices.

**Here's the code**

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const {Employees} = require('../database.js');


module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('employee')
        .setDescription('Zarządzanie pracownikami')
        .addSubcommand(subcommand =>
            subcommand
                .setName('add')
                .setDescription('Dodaj pracownika do bazy danych')
                .addUserOption(option =>
                    option.setName('clientid')
                        .setDescription('Użytkownik Discord')
                        .setRequired(true))
                .addStringOption(option =>
                    option.setName('icname')
                        .setDescription('Imię i nazwisko postaci IC')
                        .setRequired(true)))
        .addSubcommand(subcommand =>
            subcommand
                .setName('remove')
                .setDescription('Usuń pracownika z bazy danych')
                .addStringOption(option =>
                    option.setName('clientid')
                    .setDescription('Użytkownik Discord')
                    .setRequired(true)
                    .addChoices({name: "Elliot Miller", value: "123456789"}))),
    async execute(interaction) {
        const currentTime = new Date();

        if (interaction.options.getSubcommand() === 'add') {
            const user = interaction.options.getUser('clientid');
            const icname = interaction.options.getString('icname');

            try {
                const employee = await Employees.create({
                    name: icname,
                    clientid: user,
                });

                await interaction.reply({content: `Pomyślnie dodano użytkownika ${user} z postacią **${icname}** do bazy danych`, ephermal: false});
            } catch (error) {
                if (error.name === 'SequelizeUniqueConstraintError') {
                    return interaction.reply({content: `Ten użytkownik został już dodany`, ephermal: true});
                }

                await interaction.reply({content: 'Wystąpił nieznany błąd!', ephermal: true});
                return interaction.followUp(error.message);
            }
        } else if (interaction.options.getSubcommand() === 'remove') {
            // let option = interaction.options.get("clientid")
            
            // console.log(option.value);
        }
    },
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Edit

Turns out I had outdated @discordjs/builders, updating it fixed my problem with `.addChoices({..})` not working. Make sure your version is at least `0.15.0` if you're having the same issues.

## Old Comment

So I found out how to make it work, I thought I only could use specific functions but turns out I can make a loop.

So on line 29 I fetched data from the database and looped through it adding choices for every entry. It doesn't matter anyway because even when you use `addChoice()` more than once only the first choice is available from what I've seen. I think you simply can't use `addChoices()` when creating a command in a separate file and exporting it. Even if you can it's not a good solution in my situation since you can have a maximum of 25 choices which I will easily exceed.

Updated Code

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const {Employees} = require('../database.js');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('employee')
        .setDescription('Zarządzanie pracownikami')
        .addSubcommand(subcommand =>
            subcommand
                .setName('add')
                .setDescription('Dodaj pracownika do bazy danych')
                .addUserOption(option =>
                    option.setName('clientid')
                        .setDescription('Użytkownik Discord')
                        .setRequired(true))
                .addStringOption(option =>
                    option.setName('icname')
                        .setDescription('Imię i nazwisko postaci IC')
                        .setRequired(true)))
        .addSubcommand(subcommand =>
            subcommand
                .setName('remove')
                .setDescription('Usuń pracownika z bazy danych')
                .addStringOption(option =>
                    option.setName('clientid')
                    .setDescription('Użytkownik Discord')
                    .setRequired(true),
                    Employees.findAll({
                        raw: true, 
                        attributes: ['name', 'clientid']
                    }).then(listOfEmployees => {
                        for (let element of listOfEmployees) {
                            subcommand.addStringOption(option => option.addChoice(element.name, element.clientid))
                        }
                    })))
        .addSubcommand(subcommand =>
            subcommand
                .setName('list')
                .setDescription('Pokaze listę pracowników w bazie danych')),
    async execute(interaction) {
        const currentTime = new Date();

        if (interaction.options.getSubcommand() === 'add') {
            const user = interaction.options.getUser('clientid');
            const icname = interaction.options.getString('icname');

            try {
                const employee = await Employees.create({
                    name: icname,
                    clientid: user,
                });

                await interaction.reply({content: `Pomyślnie dodano użytkownika ${user} z postacią **${icname}** do bazy danych`, ephermal: true});
            } catch (error) {
                if (error.name === 'SequelizeUniqueConstraintError') {
                    return interaction.reply({content: `Ten użytkownik został już dodany`, ephermal: true});
                }

                await interaction.reply({content: 'Wystąpił nieznany błąd!', ephermal: true});
                return interaction.followUp(error.message);
            }
        } else if (interaction.options.getSubcommand() === 'remove') {
            console.log(interaction)
        } else if (interaction.options.getSubcommand() === 'list') {
            const employeeList = await Employees.findAll({ attributes: ['name', 'clientid'] });

            const employeeString = employeeList.map(t => t.name).join(', ') || 'No tags set.'

            return interaction.reply(`Lista pracowników: ${employeeString}`);
        }
    },
};
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Simple fix. On line 29, you give an object on the `#addChoices()` function. You need an array. Replace this:

```js
.addChoices({name: "Elliot Miller", value: "123456789"})))
```

with this:

```js
.addChoices([{name: "Elliot Miller", value: "123456789"}])))
```

Comment: It's still an object so I get the same error

Comment: @CanExiOne You are adding only one choice option. Maybe use the .addChoice({...}) function?

Comment: Turns out I had outdated discordjs builders so .addChoices({...}) works now.